# Passar argumentos para o makefile

Tags: makefile

Tenho uma pasta com uma série de arquivos LaTeX:

```
arquivo_001.tex
arquivo_002.tex
arquivo_003.tex
arquivo_004.tex
```

Minha ideia é escrever um makefile que me permita fazer algo do tipo `make 004` e ele compilasse apenas o arquivo `arquivo_004.tex`.

Descobri que usa `$@` dentro do makefile usa o primeiro argumento, então tentei um makefile contendo

```
all:
    pdflatex Invoice_GabrielKoscky_0$@.tex
```

Mas recebo:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `10'.  Stop.
```

O que faz todo sentido. Então tentei chamar `make all 10`, mas aí pdflatex não encontra o arquivo `arquivo_all.tex`, o que também faz todo sentido.

Existe alguma forma de pegar esse segundo argumento? O que eu quero fazer deve ser feito de outra forma?

Comment: Me parece que o make considera tudo que não é atributo como goal. E se usasse atributos como `make GDK="004"`, por exemplo, e `${GDK}` ?

Comment: Nao sei se é um problema real ou pergunta canônica, de qq forma aqui deve ter alguma referência boa pra quem for responder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/

Comment: @Bacco Eu tinha visto por aí que talvez o caminho fosse fazer algo como `make file="004"` mas me pareceu mais complicado do que poderia ser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar uma regra que seja apenas um padrão para redirecionar para alguma outra regra. Assim ela vai capturar qualquer coisa que venha da linha de comando. Observe:

```make
%: arquivo_%.pdf
    @# empty line

arquivo_%.pdf: arquivo_%.tex
    @echo Produce $@ from $^
```

Tendo isso, executar `make 003` vai exibir: *"Produce arquivo_003.pdf from arquivo_003.tex"*.
Pode também chamar em cadeia, por exemplo: `make 003 004 005`.

Note, no entanto, que é **necessário** ter ao menos uma linha de comando na regra usada para redirecionar, caso contrário ela é ignorada. Usei ali um comentário com saída suprimida, equivalente a um noop.

---

Ainda outra opção é usar uma variável cujo valor padrão seja produzir tudo. Essa solução é muito mais limpa na realidade. Em primeiro lugar definir uma variável cujo valor seja os números a se produzir. Assim:

```make
PRODUCE = $(patsubst arquivo_%.tex,%,$(wildcard arquivo_*.tex))
```

Se você tem os arquivos `arquivo_001.tex` e `arquivo_003.tex` no seu diretório, então `PRODUCE=001 003`.

Sem seguida, dado uma variável `PRODUCE`, calcular qual o nome dos arquivos alvos, os pdfs:

```make
PRODUCE_PDF = $(addprefix arquivo_,$(addsuffix .pdf,$(PRODUCE)))
```

Se `PRODUCE=001 003`, então `PRODUCE_PDR=arquivo_001.pdf arquivo_003.pdf`.

Agora é uma mera questão de fazer a regra padrão produzir os pdfs. Assim:

```make
all: $(PRODUCE_PDF)

arquivo_%.pdf: arquivo_%.tex
    @echo Produce $@ from $^
```

Se você invocar `make` sem argumentos, vai produzir todos os pdfs. Você pode especificar assim: `make PRODUCE=005`. Ou ainda: `make PRODUCE="005 006 002"`.

Comment: Não só resolveu o problema como ainda ajudou a explicar um monte de outras dúvidas que eu tive lendo um [makefile de exemplo](http://legacy.spa.aalto.fi/u/mairas/UltimateLatexMakefile/Makefile) que eu encontrei